# Android - Design Custom Switch With Text and Thumb - Track

Tags: android, xml, uiswitch

I want to create a custom switch. My expected output is like these pictures;

[image: first view]

[image: second view]

As I researched, there are many ways to do it with `switch`, `horizontal radio groups`, `segmented controls`.

So I tried to do my expected output. My codes are like this;

drawable/switch_track_green.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="11mm"
        android:height="4.2mm">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3.7mm" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.3mm"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <solid android:color="@color/teal_200" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/signInLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/cSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="4mm"
        android:switchMinWidth="11mm"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cSwitch_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2mm"
        android:layout_marginStart="2mm"
        android:text="ON"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/cSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cSwitch" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.design_example;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Switch cSwitch = findViewById(R.id.cSwitch);
        final TextView cSwitchText = findViewById(R.id.cSwitch_textView);
        cSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.signInLayout);
                ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintSet.connect(R.id.cSwitch_textView, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.cSwitch, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
                constraintSet.connect(R.id.cSwitch_textView, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.cSwitch, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
                cSwitch.setThumbDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.switch_track_green));

                if (isChecked) {
                    cSwitchText.setText("ON");
                    constraintSet.connect(R.id.cSwitch_textView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.cSwitch, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
                    constraintSet.connect(R.id.cSwitch_textView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.UNSET, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
                    cSwitch.setTrackDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.switch_track_green));
                } else {
                    cSwitchText.setText("OFF");
                    constraintSet.connect(R.id.cSwitch_textView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.cSwitch, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
                    constraintSet.connect(R.id.cSwitch_textView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.UNSET, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
                    cSwitch.setTrackDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.switch_track_green));
                }
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But now I have some problems;

1. At first open, I see default gray switch, not my custom switch.
2. When I open it, there is a track on both two sides. And, I don't see "OFF" text.
3. When I close it, I don't see "ON" text.

Can you help me to solve these problems? If possible, can you help me to create my expected output?

Comment: Problem 1: You are applying your drawable file on the `cSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`, that's why it's not like you want when you open your app, cause it will be applied only when you will toggle the switch..